# Bootstrap datepicker not working in FireFox and IE

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need some help with Bootstrap `datapicker`.
I am using MVC6 with Bootstrap 3.3.5 and jQuery 2.1.4.

I have added the following two lines in my `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap datepicker3.css" />
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I am using the following input control in my view

```
<input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

I have also tried adding the following script in my view but its still not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>
```

However, the date control is **showing in Chrome v51** and it **does not show in FireFox v47 and IE 11**. Please see Chrome screenshot below

[image]

I appreciate any help guys. Thank you so much.

Comment: Based on the `yyyy-mm-dd` I think you're probably using `<input type="date"...`, which [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) in IE and Firefox. Can you try and specify the type to `"text"`

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your advice. I have tried to use `type="text"` but it does not work. Its not even working in Chrome.

Comment: What plugin are you using? As far as I'm aware, bootstrap doesn't offer a default date-picker.

Comment: I have jQuery 2.1.4 in my project but it seems like it does not have a datepicker. I am still trying to see if I can use a `jQuery datapicker` instead. Thank you.

Comment: ah, that's jQuery UI datepicker, which is different from bootstrap, but that doesn't make sense based on your script you're including. jQuery itself has no datepicker plug in

Comment: @Charles Now I am trying to use jQuery UI Widget. I have included the lines below but still no luck. `<link href="~/lib/jquery/ui/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/ui/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. And in my view I have added `<input asp-for="DateOfBirth" id="datepicker" type="text" />`. The script `<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>`